# Output is empty

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to scala. I have written a sample code which reads from csv after taking reference from websites. I am executing the code in Databricks. Here is the sample one

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.io.IOException    
import spark.implicits._    
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


    
object Sample{
def main(args:Array[String]){
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Read_Events").setMaster("yarn-cluster")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val schema = StructType(List(
    StructField("id", LongType, nullable = true),
    StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("value", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("timestamp", LongType, nullable = true)))//Creating the schema
    
try{
val myDF = spark.read.schema(schema).option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/tru.csv")
           
  myDF.show()
}


catch {
         case ex: FileNotFoundException =>{
            println("Input file not available in path")
         }

  
         case ex: IOException => {
            println("IO Exception")
      }}

}
}
```

Seems the `df.show()` is not outputting

Seems I am doing something wrong. Any guidance would be Great!

Answer (score 0):

- In this code, you have created an object called `Sample` inside which you have code for reading the csv.
- When I implemented the same code, it gave the following output. But `myDf.show()` does not give any output as well.

[image]

- Here, we defined only the `Sample` object. We need to run the main() function in this `Sample` object to get the output. You can use the following code:

```
%scala

Sample.main(Array())
```

[image]

**NOTE:** Instead of this, you can directly write the contents of main() function in a scala cell to get the output directly.

Comment: It's *really* important to provide properly formatted text, not images of text. Please read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)